# More Multiply defined symbols

Tags: c++

I was going over this [article](http://daniel-albuschat.blogspot.com/2010/08/what-include-guards-in-c-are-and-what.html) and it talks about the compile process (pre-process,compile,link). I understand that include guards simply solve the issue of preventing multiple inclusions in the same translation unit. So if I have the following scenario :

```
File : Common.h
----------------
#ifndef External_Header
#include "iostream"
#define External_Header
std::string R = "dsds";
#endif
```

Now I have two cpp files both of them include this header file. I understand why I get the linker error `"fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found".` What I am curious about is why I dont get the same linker error when I define a struct instead of a string.

Any thoughts or ideas that might clarify this.

```
     File : Common.h
     ----------------
    #ifndef External_Header
    #include "iostream"
    #define External_Header
    struct mystruct
    {
        int a;
    };
    #endif
```

Comment: "why I dont get the same linker error when I define a struct instead of a string" - because in the second case you're not declaring any variables, you're declaring a *type*, (and with the header-guards, only once per translation unit). Put a `myvar;` after the closing curly of that struct definition and you'll once-again have your duplicate symbol error. The *linker* error you're receiving in the first case is due to identical symbols being declared in *multiple* translation units, and the linker has no idea which to pick for global resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be that you are creating a variable in the one case, but in the other case defining a new type. To verify this may try the following code.

```
struct mystruct
{
    int a;
} myTestVar;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because `struct`s are not symbols.

The C++ standard explicitly allows us to redefine types in different translation units... as long as their definition doesn't change.

> `[C++11: 3.2/1]:` No translation unit shall contain more than one definition of any variable, function, class type, enumeration type, or template.
>
> `[C++11: 3.2/3]:` Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used in that program; no diagnostic required. *[..]*

Notice how types are mentioned in the former rule but not the latter. This is made explicit a little later on:

> `[C++11: 3.2/5]:` There can be more than one definition of a class type *[..]* in a program provided that each definition appears in a different translation unit, and provided the definitions satisfy the following requirements. Given such an entity named `D` defined in more than one translation unit, then
>
> - each definition of `D` shall consist of the same sequence of tokens;
> - *[..]*

Cross-translation-unit programming would be impossibly difficult if it weren't for this distinction.